# Python/Datetime/Pandas - Changing datetime format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have this Pandas dataframe:

```
             Value
Date
2015-06-01     6.9
2015-07-01     7.5
2015-08-01     7.6
2015-09-01     7.6
2015-10-01     7.9
2015-11-01     7.5
```

I'm accessing its last index item with this code:

```
somedate=dict.index[-1]
```

It is already in a datetime format. When I `print somedate` I get the following:

```
2015-11-01 00:00:00
2015-11-01 00:00:00
```

(not sure why it comes in two lines, but it is working fine anyway)

I'm using this same date to build another dataframe from Pandas:

```
            Prediction  MAPE  Score
2015-11-01        7.93  1.83      1
```

Well, all I need is that instead of  `2015-11-01` in this last frame, it shows up only as `2015-11`.

Can I work this out in the variable somedate or that's something I need to adjust when building the dataframe?

OBS.: I tried to use datetime.strptime, however it seems only to work on string dates, not on timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
print df

#            Prediction  MAPE  Score
#                                   
#2015-11-01        7.93  1.83      1

print df.index

#DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'', freq=None)

df.index = df.index.to_period('M')
print df

#         Prediction  MAPE  Score
#                                
#2015-11        7.93  1.83      1
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html):

```
df = df.to_period('M')
print df

#         Prediction  MAPE  Score
#                                
#2015-11        7.93  1.83      1
```

EDIT:

I think `dtype` of index is not `datetime` but `object`, so you can convert it:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Prediction;MAPE;Score
2015-11-01;7.93;1.83;1"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None)
df.index.name = ''    
print df

#            Prediction  MAPE  Score
#                                   
#2015-11-01        7.93  1.83      1

print df.index
#Index([u'2015-11-01'], dtype='object', name=u'')

#convert index to datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.to_period('M')
print df

#         Prediction  MAPE  Score
#                                
#2015-11        7.93  1.83      1
```

Comment: I'm getting this: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'. Any idea?